# Inserting items entered into QTableWidget to sqlite3 database

Tags: sqlite, user-input, qtablewidget, pyqt6

I am unsure as to how to capture the data entered into cells in the QTableWidget to upload them to the sqlite db.

The only issue I'm facing is how to set the data inputted to the variables: qualification, subjectname and examboard
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Subjects(Qualification, SubjectName, ExamBoard) VALUES (?,?,?)",(qualification, subjectname, examboard)

Comment: Qt provides useful and reliable classes in its [QtSql module](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-module.html) that can directly interface with standard Sql database engines. Maybe you should use them instead of lower level classes such as QTableWidget.